# How to move images in iOS from one directory to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filepath

In iOS I want to move images to specific location using switch when switch is on it will move image to my specified location when it turn off it will move where to it comes from.

Answer (score 4):

you can use following function to `move` all your images to new `Path`.

You need to `pass` just both `DirectoryPath` `Old` and `New`

```
- (void)moveFileFromFolder:(NSString *)oldFolderPath toFolder:(NSString *)newFolderPath {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *fileNames = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:oldFolderPath error:nil];

    for (NSString *fileName in fileNames) {

        NSString * oldFilePath = [oldFolderPath stringByAppendingString:fileName];
        NSString * newFilePath = [newFolderPath stringByAppendingString:fileName];

        NSError *error = nil;
        [fileManager moveItemAtPath:oldFilePath toPath:newFilePath error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", [error description]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` returns only the image's data, with no reference to its local storage. I haven't used it myself but I guess what you are looking for is

NSURL* localUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

At least, it's the only way I know of to retrieve any URL.

Comment: OR you can use with following way..
`UIImage * image;        
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:@"Your custom Path" atomically:YES];`